# jQuery converting date to unique format

Tags: jquery, date

Trying to convert date in one unique format with jquery-
Using below function (also, tried with others from google)

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate() ,
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
document.getElementById('printdate').innerHTML =  formatDate('07/26/2017') ;
```

I am having two date formats for input like -
1) `5/16/2017` and 2) `2017-5-16`

Expected output would be `2017-07-16`

For India Timezone, above function works as expected returning output like -
`2017-07-16` for each of above input dates.

But, If I change Timezone to US/Canada, it returning date one day before i.e.
for input date `2017-06-26`, it returns `2017-06-25` and
for input date `07/26/2017`, it returns `2017-07-26`

Here is jsfidle - https://jsfiddle.net/L1j8ho1j/2/

What is reason, it is returning one day before date?

Is there any other function to convert date, returning same input date with expected formatting?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For 'What is reason' - As you told time zone matters. India is one day ahead from US/Canada. Better use UTC time.

Comment: yes, you are right. But, if the input date is 07/26/2017, it is returning expected date format, but if input date is 2017-07-26, then only it returns one day before date.

Comment: did you tried like this - https://jsfiddle.net/L1j8ho1j/3/

Comment: that's the question. Above fiddle works accurate for India timezone. But if we change it to US/Canada, it returns different dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to using **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** then you can use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) .This can solve your issues with date timezones and date formatting.

You need to load all of the following:

- [moment](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js)
- [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.min.js)

Using it your `formatDate` method should look something like this.

```
function formatDate(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}

moment.tz.add("Asia/Kolkata|HMT +0630 IST|-5R.k -6u -5u|01212|-18LFR.k 1unn.k HB0 7zX0|15e6")
moment.tz.add("America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0")

var date = new Date();
console.log(formatDate(date, 'Asia/Kolkata'));
console.log(formatDate(date, 'America/Los_Angeles'));
```

You can get latest timezone data via [this](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json) link.