# Convert milliseconds to date in moment.js nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

i want to know how can i convert  milliseconds to date format in moment.js using nodejs.

I am using the following way:-

```
var schedule_time="1512986378692";  // Monday, 11 December 2017 15:29:38
```

schedule_time time is 11 dec, 2017 15:29:38.

But when i use the following method it give me the following result

```
moment.unix((schedule_time)/1000).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); // 2017-12-11 09:59:38
```

Comment: Perhaps this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860402/6043442

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the timezone difference. The milliseconds are of IST, but moment is by default using UTC for this on your machine.

You can try a [good library](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) which integrates well with MomentJS, and have good features for working with timezones.

To answer the quest, moment-timezone offers an API to change the timezone of the provided moment object, like this:

```
moment(1512986378692).tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Also, I didn't quite understand why are you converting the millis to seconds further.